# get an error when using threading module in flask route

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a time-consuming operation to modify the database which is triggered by request the route，So I want to perform the operation asynchronously without waiting for it to end，and return the state directly. I tried to use threading module in the route,but got this error:[image]

The following is the code：
define a model:

```
class Plan(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'opt_version_plans'

    planid = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    planname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    jobname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    branch = db.Column(db.String(32))
```

define function:

```
def test():
    time.sleep(20)
    p = Plan.query.get(1)
    print p.planname
```

route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    t = threading.Thread(target=test)
    t.start()
    return "helloworld"
```

How can I achieve my needs in this way？

Comment: Are you using sqlalchemy for your database connections? Does it work if you moved your Plan.query.get(1) command to your index() function?

Comment: Thank you! Yes,I using sqlalchemy .According to your statement，I try this:
`def test(p):
    time.sleep(20)
    print p.planname`

`@app.route('/')
def index():
    p = Plan.query.get(1)
    t = threading.Thread(target=test,args=(p,))
    t.start()
    return "helloworld"`

Comment: and It works.But what if I call the function from another module?